# Multiple selectbox's with same values using Chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-chosen

Is there a way to create multiple selectbox's with same values populated using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin or [Select2](https://select2.github.io/).

Conditions:

1. All the selectbox's should have same values
2. Single Select for each selectbox
3. Options cannot be selected twice in all of the selectbox's (eg:
   A,B,C.. are options, where A can be selected only once)
4. Option to add custom values in the selectbox, which is updated to
   all selectbox's
5. Selected values are disabled in rest of the selectbox's

Comment: I am getting performance issue while disabling them, if in case I have more than 30 selectbox's with the same data. Say 30 selectbox X 30 options = 900 times. `$select2.find("option:not(:selected)").filter(function () { return this.value == val; }).prop("disabled", true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are a few questions within here, I'll give a separate answer for all of them. Note that I am the maintainer of Select2, so **all of my answers are for Select2**. *Some will apply* to Chosen, but I can't guarantee it.

The full code is available at the bottom of this answer, as a complete runnable Stack Snippet. Individual snippets will be included beneath the questions when available.

> 1. All the selectbox's should have same values

This is something that you should be able to do without Select2 or Chosen, as it is all a matter of cloning the contents of one `<select>` to the rest of them. This can be as a simple as

```
$("select").html($(".main-select").html());
```

Which will make sure that all `<select>` boxes have the same options as the one with the class of `main-select`.

> 2. Single Select for each selectbox

Both Select2 and Chosen determine if multiple selections are allowed based on whether or not you specify the `multiple` attribute on your `<select>`. So the easy solution here is to never include it, and all of the select boxes will only allow a single selection.

> 3. Options cannot be selected twice in all of the selectbox's (eg: A,B,C.. are options, where A can be selected only once)

This one is more difficult, and the implementation will all depend on how each plugin can handle disabling options on the fly. Both plugins will trigger the `change` event when the value of the `<select>` changes, so you can detect when a new option is selected and disable it in the other `<select>` boxes. Both plugins determine if an option can be selected by checking the `disabled` property on the `<option>`, just like a browser would, so you will want to use that.

The trick here is to detect the `value` of the newly selected option and disable all other `<option>` elements in other `<select>` boxes that have that same value.

```
$select2.find("option:not(:selected)").filter(function () {
  return this.value == val;
}).prop("disabled", true);
```

Note that due to a current bug in Select2, you will need to call `removeData("data")` on those `<option>` elements to clear the cached data for the element.

> 4. Option to add custom values in the selectbox, which is updated to all selectbox's

Select2 allows you to enable custom values by setting `tags: true` when initializing Select2. Chosen does not have the ability to add custom values, so that may be a deal breaker.

> 5. Selected values are disabled in rest of the selectbox's

This is solved when solving 3.

---

```js
var $select2 = $(".select2");

// Copy the options to all selects based on the first one
$("select").html($select2.first().html());

// Initialize Select2
$select2.select2({
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: "Select an option",
  tags: true
});

// Handle disabling already-selected options
$select2.on("change", function () {
  $select2.find("option:disabled").prop("disabled", false).removeData("data");
  
  $select2.each(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    
    $select2.find("option:not(:selected)").filter(function () {
      return this.value == val;
    }).prop("disabled", true).removeData("data");
  });
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.select2 { width: 200px; }
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.js"></script>

<select class="select2">
  <option></option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>

<select class="select2"></select>
<select class="select2"></select>
<select class="select2"></select>
```

Comment: thanks. In the 4th point, new options/tags added by the user should also be appended to the other selectbox's, so the new options aren't duplicated.

Comment: I am getting **performance issue** while disabling them, if in case I have more than 30 selectbox's with the same data. Say 30 selectbox X 30 options = 900 times. `$select2.find("option:not(:selected)").filter(function () {
  return this.value == val;
}).prop("disabled", true);`